# Null matrix with constant diagonal, with same shape as another matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to multiply a numpy matrix by a scalar.  Essentially I want all values to be multiplied by the constant 40.  This would be an nxn matrix with 40's on the diagonal, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler function to use to scale this matrix.  Or how would I go about making a matrix with the same shape as my other matrix and fill in its diagonal?

Sorry if this seems a bit basic, but for some reason I couldn't find this in the doc.

Answer (score 17):

If you want a matrix with 40 on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else, you can use NumPy's function `fill_diagonal()` on a matrix of zeros.  You can thus directly do:

```
N = 100; value = 40
b = np.zeros((N, N))
np.fill_diagonal(b, value)
```

This involves only setting elements to a certain value, and is therefore likely to be faster than code involving multiplying all the elements of a matrix by a constant.  This approach also has the advantage of showing explicitly that you fill the diagonal with a specific value.

If you want the diagonal matrix `b` to be of the same size as another matrix `a`, you can use the following shortcut (no need for an explicit size `N`):

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
np.fill_diagonal(b, value)
```

Answer (score 9):

Easy:

```
N = 100
a = np.eye(N)  # Diagonal Identity 100x100 array
b = 40*a  # Multiply by a scalar
```

If you actually want a numpy matrix vs an array, you can do `a = np.asmatrix(np.eye(N))` instead. But in general `*` is element-wise multiplication in numpy.

Comment: If performance is an issue, the OP may not want to create a copy `b`, in which case `a*=40` will scale the array in-place.

Comment: `numpy.fill_diagonal()` is specifically meant to fill the diagonal with a given element. As a consequence, it is more explicit and faster than constructing the identity matrix and then multiplying all its elements by a constant.