# changing the values of the diagonal of a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

how can I change the values of the diagonal of a matrix in numpy?

I checked [Numpy modify ndarray diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394760/numpy-modify-ndarray-diagonal), but the function there is not implemented in numpy v 1.3.0.

lets say we have a np.array X and I want to set all values of the diagonal to 0.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? `np.diag_indices_from` was added in v1.4

Comment: yep, you are right, I am currently using python v 1.3.0

Comment: @LangerHansIslands Hopefully you mean numpy 1.3, not python 1.3 (which came out in the mid-nineties... :p)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Did you try `numpy.fill_diagonal`? See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852495/scaling-an-array-in-python-with-numpy) and this [discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg18274.html). Or the following from the documentation (although currently broken):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html

Comment: +1 This is the proper way to do this in numpy. The built-in is always preferable to iterating the array one element at a time using two for loops.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using a version of numpy that doesn't have `fill_diagonal` (the [right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958952/344821) to set the diagonal to a constant) or `diag_indices_from`, you can do this pretty easily with array slicing:

```
# assuming a 2d square array
n = mat.shape[0]
mat[range(n), range(n)] = 0
```

This is much faster than an explicit loop in Python, because the looping happens in C and is potentially vectorized.

One nice thing about this is that you can also fill a diagonal with a list of elements, rather than a constant value (like `diagflat`, but for modifying an existing matrix rather than making a new one). For example, this will set the diagonal of your matrix to 0, 1, 2, ...:

```
# again assuming 2d square array
n = mat.shape[0]
mat[range(n), range(n)] = range(n)
```

If you need to support more array shapes, this is more complicated (which is why fill_diagonal is nice...):

```
m[list(zip(*map(range, m.shape)))] = 0
```

(The `list` call is only necessary in Python 3, where `zip` returns an iterator.)

Comment: To make it clear for future readers, `mat[:n, :n] = 0` sets _the whole array / matrix_ to 0, not just the diagonal elements. `zip` version indeed does the diag.

Comment: @gorlum0 Whoops - thanks for pointing that out. I just edited to fix it (the `zip` isn't actually necessary there)`.

Comment: Cool, even bare `ranges`. This implicit stuff is hard to get to know.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `numpy.diag_indices_from()` to get the indices of the diagonal elements of your array. Then set the value of those indices.

```
X[np.diag_indices_from(X)] = 0.
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.rand(5, 5)

>>> print(X)
[[0.59480384 0.20133725 0.59147423 0.22640441 0.40898203]
 [0.65230581 0.57055258 0.97009881 0.58535275 0.32036626]
 [0.71524332 0.73424734 0.92461381 0.38704119 0.08147428]
 [0.18931865 0.97366736 0.11482649 0.82793141 0.13347333]
 [0.47402986 0.73329347 0.18892479 0.11883424 0.78718883]]

>>> X[np.diag_indices_from(X)] = 0
>>> print(X)
[[0.         0.20133725 0.59147423 0.22640441 0.40898203]
 [0.65230581 0.         0.97009881 0.58535275 0.32036626]
 [0.71524332 0.73424734 0.         0.38704119 0.08147428]
 [0.18931865 0.97366736 0.11482649 0.         0.13347333]
 [0.47402986 0.73329347 0.18892479 0.11883424 0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's another good way to do this. If you want a one-dimensional view of the array's main diagonal use:

```
A.ravel()[:A.shape[1]**2:A.shape[1]+1]
```

For the i'th superdiagonal use:

```
A.ravel()[i:max(0,A.shape[1]-i)*A.shape[1]:A.shape[1]+1]
```

For the i'th subdiagonal use:

```
A.ravel()[A.shape[1]*i:A.shape[1]*(i+A.shape[1]):A.shape[1]+1]
```

Or in general, for the i'th diagonal where the main diagonal is 0, the subdiagonals are negative and the superdiagonals are positive, use:

```
A.ravel()[max(i,-A.shape[1]*i):max(0,(A.shape[1]-i))*A.shape[1]:A.shape[1]+1]
```

These are *views* and not copies, so they will run faster for extracting a diagonal, but any changes made to the new array object will apply to the original array.
On my machine these run faster than the fill_diagonal function when setting the main diagonal to a constant, but that may not always be the case. They can also be used to assign an array of values to a diagonal instead of just a constant.

Notes: for small arrays it may be faster to use the `flat` attribute of the NumPy array.
If speed is a major issue it could be worth it to make `A.shape[1]` a local variable.
Also, if the array is not contiguous, `ravel()` will return a copy, so, in order to assign values to a strided slice, it will be necessary to creatively slice the original array used to generate the strided slice (if it is contiguous) or to use the `flat` attribute.

Also, it was originally planned that in NumPy 1.10 and later the 'diagonal' method of arrays will return a view instead of a copy.
That change hasn't yet been made though, but hopefully at some point this trick to get a view will no longer be necessary.
See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html

Comment: Nice and hacky, I like it! Only caveat is I think you would get the `wrap=True` behavior described in the [`np.fill_diagonal` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html). You can probably solve that adding an adequate stop value to your slices.

Comment: Thank you, good catch. I just edited it to fix that and a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
def replaceDiagonal(matrix, replacementList):
    for i in range(len(replacementList)):
        matrix[i][i] = replacementList[i]
```

Where size is n in an n x n matrix.

Comment: The comment `matrix[:n, :n] = replacement_list` by @Danica is incorrect.  That would modify the whole matrix rather than just the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959707/344821) (from nine years ago) fixed it, but I deleted this one wrong comment to avoid any chance of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = numpy.random.rand(2,2)
>>> a
array([[ 0.41668355,  0.07982691], 
       [ 0.60790982,  0.0314224 ]])
>>> a - numpy.diag(numpy.diag(a))
array([[ 0.        ,  0.07982691],
       [ 0.60790982,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following.

Assuming your matrix is 4 * 4 matrix.

```
indices_diagonal = np.diag_indices(4)

yourarray[indices_diagonal] = Val
```