# Make special diagonal matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, toeplitz

I am trying to make a numpy array that looks like this:

```
[a b c       ]
[  a b c     ]
[    a b c   ]
[      a b c ]
```

So this involves updating the main diagonal and the two diagonals above it.

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) - you can construct it using [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

first_row = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0])
first_col = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])

print(toeplitz(first_col, first_row))
# [[1 2 3 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 2 3 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use `np.indices` to get the indices of your array and then assign the values where you want.

```
a = np.zeros((5,10))
i,j = np.indices(a.shape)
```

`i,j` are the line and column indices, respectively.

```
a[i==j] = 1.
a[i==j-1] = 2.
a[i==j-2] = 3.
```

will result in:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Among all the solutions suggested, it has a good balance between simplicity and performance. I wish numpy's diag function can let me specify which super/sub diagonal I want to update and then return a view of the diagonal. This would then be the most intuitive and fastest.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

def using_tile_and_stride():
    arr = np.tile(np.array([10,20,30,0,0,0], dtype='float'), (4,1))
    row_stride, col_stride = arr.strides
    arr.strides = row_stride-col_stride, col_stride
    return arr

In [108]: using_tile_and_stride()
Out[108]: 
array([[ 10.,  20.,  30.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  10.,  20.,  30.]])
```

Other, slower alternatives include:

```
import numpy as np

import numpy.lib.stride_tricks as stride

def using_put():
    arr = np.zeros((4,6), dtype='float')
    a, b, c = 10, 20, 30
    nrows, ncols = arr.shape
    ind = (np.arange(3) + np.arange(0,(ncols+1)*nrows,ncols+1)[:,np.newaxis]).ravel()
    arr.put(ind, [a, b, c])
    return arr

def using_strides():
    return np.flipud(stride.as_strided(
        np.array([0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 30, 0, 0, 0], dtype='float'), 
        shape=(4, 6), strides = (8, 8)))
```

---

If you use `using_tile_and_stride`, note that the array is only appropriate for read-only purposes. Otherwise, if you were to try to modify the array, you might be surprised when multiple array locations change simultaneously:

```
In [32]: arr = using_tile_and_stride()

In [33]: arr[0, -1] = 100

In [34]: arr
Out[34]: 
array([[  10.,   20.,   30.,    0.,  100.],
       [ 100.,   10.,   20.,   30.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,   10.,   20.,   30.],
       [  30.,    0.,    0.,   10.,   20.]])
```

You could work around this by returning `np.ascontiguousarray(arr)` instead of just `arr`, but then `using_tile_and_stride` would be slower than `using_put`. So if you intend to modify the array, `using_put` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but I want to bump that ali_m's answer is by far the most efficient as scipy takes care of things for you.

For example, with a matrix of size `n,m = 1200`, repeatedly adding `np.diag()` calls takes `~6.14s`, Saullo G. P. Castro's answer takes `~7.7s`, and `scipy.linalg.toeplitz(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))` takes `1.57ms`.

Answer (score 0):

Using my answer to this question: [changing the values of the diagonal of a matrix in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958577/changing-the-values-of-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix-in-numpy) , you can do some tricky slicing to get a view of each diagonal, then do the assignment.
In this case it would just be:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((4,6))
# main diagonal
A.flat[:A.shape[1]**2:A.shape[1]+1] = a
# first superdiagonal
A.flat[1:max(0,A.shape[1]-1)*A.shape[1]:A.shape[1]+1] = b
# second superdiagonal
A.flat[2:max(0,A.shape[1]-2)*A.shape[1]:A.shape[1]+1] = c
```