# numpy: fill offset diagonal with different values

Tags: python, numpy

I need to make a `n*n` matrix `m` whose elements follow `m(i,i+1)=sqrt(i)` and 0 otherwise. For example, for `n=5`, we should have

```
[0 a 0 0 0]
[0 0 b 0 0]
[0 0 0 c 0]
[0 0 0 0 d]
[0 0 0 0 0]
```

where `{a,b,c,d}=sqrt({1,2,3,4})`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026541/make-special-diagonal-matrix-in-numpy) is a solution for a constant tri-diagonal matrix, but my case is a bit more complicated than that. I know I can do that with a loop or with list comprehension, but are there other ways? `n` can be potentially big.

e.g. (list comprehension code)

```
ele=lambda i,j:sqrt(i+1) if j-i==1 else 0

[[ele(i,j) for j in range(0,6)] for i in range(0,6)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way could be to create the array of zeros and then use indexing to select and fill the desired indices with the square-root values.

For example:

```
>>> z = np.zeros((5,5))
>>> rng = np.arange(4)
>>> z[rng, rng+1] = np.sqrt(rng+1)
>>> z
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.73205081,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: second line should be `rng = np.arange(4)`

Answer (score 14):

You can straightforwardly use `np.diag`:

```
>>> d = np.sqrt(1 + np.arange(4))
>>> np.diag(d, 1)
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.73205081,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

The second argument of `np.diag` specifies the diagonal in question.

Comment: This is ingenious, there should be an example in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html)!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late obviously but i want to introduce numpy diagflat method in this question. It can be done in this way:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5

aux = np.arange(1 , n)
aux = np.sqrt(aux)

A = np.diagflat(aux , 1)
```

Comment: In what way is this different from just using `np.diag(aux, 1)`?