# Special Matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a numpy array that looks like this:

```
m = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I have seen this answer [Make special diagonal matrix in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026541/make-special-diagonal-matrix-in-numpy) and I have this:

```
a = np.zeros(3,9)
a[0, 0] = 1
a[0, 1] = 1
a[0, 2] = 1
a[1, 3] = 1
a[1, 4] = 1
a[1, 5] = 1
a[2, 6] = 1
a[2, 7] = 1
a[2, 8] = 1
```

But I want to use a 'for' cicle, How I can fill the diagonal efficiently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to simply stretch an identity array horizontally;

```
> np.repeat(np.identity(3, dtype=int), 3, axis=1)

array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 5):

If `m` denotes the number of `1`s in a row and `n` the number of rows, two approaches could be listed to solve it.

Using [`np.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) this is straight-forward, like so -

```
def kron_based(m,n):
    return np.kron(np.eye(n,dtype=int), np.ones(m,dtype=int))
```

Using zeros initialization and filling would be -

```
def initialization_based(m,n):
    A = np.zeros((n,n*m),dtype=int)
    A.reshape(n,n,m)[np.eye(n,dtype=bool)] = 1
    return A
```

Sample run -

```
In [54]: m = 4 # Number of 1s in a row. Note that this is 3 for your case
    ...: n = 3 # Number of rows
    ...: 

In [55]: initialization_based(m,n)
Out[55]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [56]: kron_based(m,n)
Out[56]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.tile(np.eye(3, dtype=int)[:,:, np.newaxis], (1,1,3)).reshape(3,-1)`

However, @joachim-isaksson's answer is slightly more compact.

Alternative solution (based on LA matrix multiplication `dot` function):

`np.dot(np.eye(3, dtype=int)[:,:, np.newaxis], np.array([[1,1,1],])).reshape(3,-1)`

Update: `toeplitz()` can be useful in building special matrices:

`from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
(np.abs((toeplitz(np.arange(12),-np.arange(12)))[1:8:3,:9])<2)*1`

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to complete the series with the obvious alternative, there is also `block_diag`onal:

```
 import numpy as np
 import scipy as sp

 sp.linalg.block_diag(*[np.ones((1,3),dtype=int)]*5)
```

or if you are into that kind of stuff

```
 sp.linalg.block_diag(*[[1]*3]*5)
```