# Create double row diagonal matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal

I am trying to make a special diagonal matrix that looks like this:

```
[[1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1]]
```

It is slightly different from the question here: [Make special diagonal matrix in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026541/make-special-diagonal-matrix-in-numpy)

I tried tweaking the solution but couldn't quite get it.
Appreciate any advice on how to achieve this efficiently.

Comment: `np.repeat(np.eye(3, dtype=int), repeats=2, axis=1)`

Comment: `a = np.zeros((3, 6), dtype=int); j = np.arange(a.shape[1]); a[j // 2, j] = 1`

Comment: And so on . . . :)

Comment: great!! please add it as an answer and i will accept it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as in comments, but :

```
a=4 # number of rows
b=a*2 #number of columns
np.array((([1]*2+[0]*b)*a)[:-b]).reshape(a,b)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

works for any `a`.